# Put Array as key for Object PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I'm building a simple service for mobile apps with php which give a JSON to mobile apps. I have two table in code, below the snippet :

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$sql_results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table-images`");
$sql_results_1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table-code` WHERE id='$id'");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_results)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
}
echo'{"response":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
```

Resul code above :

```
{
"response": [{
    "id": "31",
    "shirtImage": "Content\/Images\/Short Sleeve\/874be7b82812f76c944d71706c9651eb.gif"
}, {
    "id": "32",
    "shirtImage": "Content\/Images\/Short Sleeve\/b-Cleaned.png"
}]
}
```

I want to put result of `sql_results_1` as key to the result, here I the JSON I need :

```
{
"response": [{
    "id": "31",
    "shirtImage": "Content\/Images\/Short Sleeve\/874be7b82812f76c944d71706c9651eb.gif",
    "idcode": [{
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 1,
        "Z": 2
    }]
}, {
    "id": "32",
    "shirtImage": "Content\/Images\/Short Sleeve\/b-Cleaned.png",
    "idcode": [{
        "X": 2,
        "Y": 1,
        "Z": 0
    }]
}]
}
```

Where key `idcode` is result from '$sql_results_1'. I new in PHP programming, I read some question regarding my own but the result is not I expect.

### Edit

As @Ashu answer, here the code now :

```
$final_array = array();
$i=0;

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_results)) {
    array_push($final_array,$r);
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table-code` WHERE id='".$row['id']."'");
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       $final_array[$i]["idcode"] = array("x"=>$r['x']);
    }
    $i++; 
}
```

But the key `idcode` is JSONObject `"idcode":{x=0}`, I need it as JSONArray `"idcode":[{x=0}]`

Comment: idcode value is ={"X": 0,"Y": 1, "Z": 2} on single row or xyz is on separate rows...please mention table 2 structure for 'idcode'

Comment: how looks like `$sql_results_1` ? what did you try by far ?

Comment: @Ashu they are is single row (x, y and z) is a field from table `table-code`

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend PDO over mysqli. But with mysqli things are as follows:

The fetch assoc function:

> Returns an associative array of strings representing the fetched row
>   in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of
>   one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in
>   resultset.
>
> If two or more columns of the result have the same field names, the
>   last column will take precedence. To access the other column(s) of the
>   same name, you either need to access the result with numeric indices
>   by using mysqli_fetch_row() or add alias names.

As you push everything to an array you have an multidimensional array $rows containing all results:

```
 $rows[];
```

Go with:

```
foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table-code` WHERE id='".$row['id']."'");
   $row["idcode"] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   $rows[$key] = $row;
}
```

Untested. Is it giving you the correct idea?

Comment: yes, i use your concept and combine with @Ashu answer. But the key `idcode` is JSONObject, I need it as JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

1st result store into array :

```
$final_array = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_results)) {
   array_push($final_array,$r);
}
```

2nd table result, you have to create idcode key in final_array using $i.

```
$i=0;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_results1)) {
   $final_array[$i]["idcode"] = array("x"=>$r['x'],"y"=>$r['y'],"z"=>$r['z']);
   $i++; 
}

echo'{"response":'.json_encode($final_array).'}';
```

Comment: I modify your answer, i put the second step in first step and its working, but in line `   $final_array[$i]["idcode"] = array("x"=>$r['x'],"y"=>$r['y'],"z"=>$r['z']);
` is give me JSONObject instead JSONArray. I need JSONArray in key `idcode`.